# Populate Contact Information using Selenium

Tags: dynamic, selenium

I am very new to Selenium. Basically i need to populate the fields below using selenium web-driver in Visual Studio. Because of the lightning components i am having trouble using XPath. Need help resolving this issue

I tried finding the element and also by using the XPath with the code below but with no luck:

driver.FindElement(By.Name("First Name")).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='oneHeader']/div[3]/one-appnav/div/one-app-nav-bar/nav/div/one-app-nav-bar-item-root[5]/a/span")).Click();

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] your question, and take a moment to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Use the below XPATHs for identifying the fields:

```
String fnameXpath  = "//label[span[text()='First Name']]/following-sibling::input";

driver.findElement(By.xpath(fnameXpath)).sendKeys("First Name");
```

Similarly, update the above XPath with the right text of the field then you will be able to Identify other fields as well.

For example: For Last Name:

```
String lnameXpath  = "//label[span[text()='Last Name']]/following-sibling::input";

String emailXpath  = "//label[span[text()='Email']]/following-sibling::input";

String phoneXpath  = "//label[span[text()='Phone']]/following-sibling::input";
```